# Graphics Glitching Solved With New User Account

Tags: catalina, video, user-account, graphics

*Mid-2015 MacBook Pro 15", Catalina 10.15.3, twin 4K displays*

**Problem**
Graphics glitching: unable to maintain smooth video playback on any video source, frames dropped. A few times a minute I'll get a yellow or red flash covering half of one screen.

**Solution**
Having created and logged in as a new administrator user, playback is smooth: no dropped frames and no colour flashes.

**Steps Taken**
Before creating a new user, I tried removing apps, specifically browsers using WideVine to display Netflix. Also reset PRAM and SMC. No change.

**What I Need**
I'd like to "fix" my usual user profile so I don't have to use a second profile on my machine. Since I have a working profile and a broken one, I need to isolate the difference between the two (as it relates to graphics performance) and make my regular (broken) profile work like my new (working) one.

Comment: Did you boot your machine in Safemode and checked it?

Comment: @Udhy YouTube is smooth in safe mode but no audio and Netflix won't play at all. Thanks for your comment.